# android:database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sql, database

**DATABASE HELPER-METHOD**

```
public Cursor displayInfo(String userID){
    String[] user_ID={userID};
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor2=db.rawQuery("select NAME,EMAIL,USER_ID from "+ TABLE_EMP_INFO +" where USER_ID=?",user_ID);
    return cursor2;
}
```

**USER ACTIVITY**

```
public class UserMain extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper mydb;
    String data;
    TextView textName,textUserID,textEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_main);

         data = getIntent().getStringExtra("UserID");
        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        display();
        textName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textName);
        textUserID=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textUserID);
        textEmail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEmail);


    }
public void display(){

        Cursor  c=mydb.displayInfo(data);
        String[] data={"","",""};

        if (c.moveToFirst()){

            int i=0;
            do{
                 data[i] = c.getString(i);
                ++i;
            }while(c.moveToNext()&&i<3);
        }
        c.close();
        textName.setText(data[0]);
        textEmail.setText(data[1]);
        textUserID.setText(data[2]);

    }

}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
04-01 17:43:00.527 12629-12629/com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana, PID: 12629
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana/com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana.UserMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana.UserMain.display(UserMain.java:78)
                                                                                          at com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana.UserMain.onCreate(UserMain.java:33)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

The method display in UserMain class calls DisplayInfo in DATABASE HELPER.
DATABASE HELPER returns the cursor,but as seen in the Logcat the cursor seems to be empty. I've been Trying to resolve the issue from a 5-6Hours but couldn't find any help.

Comment: Check the length of the cursor

Comment: second argument of rawQuery is String[] array and you've inserted string argument.

Comment: cursor has reached end,,it cannot move to next!

Comment: If the cursor has reached the end it means cursor is empty. I cannot figure out why is the Cursor null, I've used same logic for other methods too there is no problem in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function with following function

```
public void display(){
        Cursor  c=mydb.displayInfo(data);
        String[] data={"","",""};
        if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                data[i] = c.getString(i);
            }
        }
        c.close();
        textName.setText(""+data[0]);
        textEmail.setText(""+data[1]);
        textUserID.setText(""+data[2]);
    }
```

Comment: No,this didn't work. The error is still the same. What I think is that there is a problem in passing the argument in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
    public void display(){

            Cursor  c=mydb.displayInfo(data);
            String[] data={"","",""};

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {

                   for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

                        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                                 data[i] = c.getString(i);
                        }

                    }

            }

            c.close();

            textName.setText(""+data[0]);
            textEmail.setText(""+data[1]);      
            textUserID.setText(""+data[2]);

     }
```